# Share files with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, babylonjs

I am using Node.js and Socket.io for my web application.

I want to broadcast a file which can be somehow large (>15 Mb)to all the connected sockets and then use it in my clients. Is there a way to do this?

PS: if you can have a demo with babylon.js + socket.io that would be awesome

**EDIT**:
As requested, my server code:

```
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { createSocketServer} from "./socket";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";

const port = 3000;

// Create a new express application instance
const app: express.Application = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

const server = createServer(app);

// create a socket.io server
createSocketServer(server);

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(port,'0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port + ' !');
});
```

Babylon Assets Loading code:

```
this.assetsManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(this.scene);

this.assetsManager.addMeshTask('obj task', '',
      'http://192.168.0.100:3000/babylon-files/dir1/', 'objectFile.obj');
this.assetsManager.addMeshTask('mtl task', '',
      'http://192.168.0.100:3000/babylon-files/dir1/', 'materialFile.mtl');
this.assetsManager.addTextureTask('text1 task',
      'http://192.168.0.100:3000/babylon-files/dir1/texture1.jpg');
this.assetsManager.addTextureTask('text2 task',
      'http://192.168.0.100:3000/babylon-files/dir1/texture2.jpg');

this.assetsManager.onFinish = ((tasks) => {
      this.engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
        this.scene.render();
      });
}).bind(this);

this.assetsManager.load();
```

Comment: sure load the files with FileReader and emit like normal, socket.io can handle binary, array buffers etc np

Comment: If you're going to send them to the client and not have the client store them anywhere, then yes, they will be in RAM.  Whether your babylon client code can use them from ram depends entirely upon that code and whether it supports that type of access.  What exactly are you sending to the client?  Is it code?  Or is it data?  If data, what type of data?

Comment: @jfriend00 for example I'll send a 3d object files so basically in the directory there would be an .obj file a .mat file and some .jpg textures files

Comment: If BabylonJS allows you to load the object files from a string or from some sort of typed array instead of from a file, then it should be doable.

Comment: @Observablerxjs Why are you not telling BabylonJS over socket.io to load the file ? BabylonJS has a assets loader

Comment: @Marc so your idea is to store the model in a github repo then tell to babylon.js to load the file from the github repo? Because right now my model is not on github it's on the server's filesystem

Comment: @Observablerxjs No. Where are you hosting your Babylon app? Store your *.obj & *.mtl files on the same server and tell Bayblon via socket.io to load asset: `x`, `y` & `z`.

Comment: @Marc Can you please post an answer on how to do that? This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @Observablerxjs https://pastebin.com/6ee48vfk

Comment: @Marc In order for your code to work, the client should have the file in his filesystem so babylon can access it by his filename, otherwise when I call BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load, babylon will not find it. The server is the only one who have the files so that's why I want to broadcast them to the other clients.

Comment: @Observablerxjs the client/browser has no access to the user its file system, and thats good! You need to load the files via http from the webserver, take a look on my anwser below and leave a comment if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

You sould store the `*.obj` & `*.mtl` files on the same server.

Note that your node & webserver code cant run on the same port.
You should use a reverse proxy or listen on diffrent ports.

This prevents cross site issues.
For example: create in your webserver a directory that is public accessable: http://example.com/assets/babylon-files

In your **node** code you can now trigger clients to load files from that path:

```js
// socket.io logic above
// waiting for connetions, auth, etc...

// tell conencted clients what the should load from 
// http://example.com/assets/babylon-files
socket.broadcast.emit('loadAsset', 'house.obj');
socket.broadcast.emit('loadAsset', 'car.obj');
socket.broadcast.emit('loadAsset', 'wall.obj');
```

The client should looks something like this:

```js
// listen for socket.io events from server here
io.on("loadAsset", (filename) => {

  // tell babylon to load assets
  BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("/assets/babylon-files", filename, engine, function (scene) {
   // do something with the scene
  });

  // - or -

  // tell babylon to append assets
  BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("/assets/babylon-files", filename, function (scene) {
    // do something with the scene
  });


});
```

On the same way you can send binary data to the clients:

```js
fs.readFile("/path/to/obj<or>mtl/file", (err, buff) => {

    if (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
        return;
    }

    socket.binary(true).emit("loadAsset", buff);

});
```

Comment: Once I send binary data to the clients, I convert it to as `const data = new Uint8Array(buff);` and then, how can I load this data on babylon?

Comment: Thats the point, i dont know if babylon support this!
I still dont get why you dont use the XHR requets from the babylon assets loader.
Whats the reason you dont want to use it ?!

Comment: To do it I need to host my asset files on a web server and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Observablerxjs and where are you hosting your node app, where are you serving your html/js/css & babylon/ files ? You need! a Webserver, even if your write one in node. If so, serve the files from there...

Comment: ok so for example let's assume the ip address of my web server (a node.js web server) is: 10.0.1.1 what's the url I'll pass to babylon?

Comment: @Observablerxjs This dependes on your server code, can post the server code too ?
But in general, just replace "example.com" with your IP adress. NOTE: you have to adjust the paths to the assets. If you serve your babylon app from 10.0.1.1 then my code would try to fetch the assets from "http://10.0.1.1/assets/babylon-files". The reason for this is: babylon do requets to the "window.location" and concat the given path. Do you have a  public repository ?

Comment: My server code is very basic, I just edited my post. Also I'm not sure what is a public repository or how to create one.

Comment: @Observablerxjs 1) Are you serving the babylon app via express ? If so: create a "babylon-files" folder inside your "public" folder, there you put all your files that you want babylon to load via socket.io, ready to go! NOTE to remove the "assets" folder in the path from the client code

Comment: ok last thing, I didn't find how to use the sceneLoader you suggested in your answer so I went for the assetsManager, everything seems to be sent to the client correctly, I can see it in the browser's developper tools but somehow babylon.js doesn't load my model. I edited my post with the assetLoading code

Comment: @Observablerxjs can you please provide a *full* working example, server+client inclund all assets (obj,mtl,jpg) files. the best is to upload them on github.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share all the app, but here is a link to an example of a model I want to generate with babylon: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n6tI6AQGkCqaYfFnrJpGZRc86dPPmAaH/view ,also concerning the assetsManager is it correct the way I implemented it?

Comment: @Observablerxjs Sorry, but i cant help you without the whole app. https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/load_from_any_file_type#sceneloaderappend `BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append(...)` should work with the right plugins NOTE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210902/discussion-between-observablerxjs-and-marc).